# Android: Displaying an integer

Tags: android, textview

When I comment out counter and run it with message, it works fine.  It will not display an integer though.  During my research, I have found no difference between the example code to display a String versus displaying an integer.  Perhaps there is a guide somewhere I can review?  Or a simple answer would also be appreciated.  Thanks.

```
package com.evorlor.testcode;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SupWorld extends Activity {

    private String message;
    private int counter;

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        message = "Sup world.";
        counter = 123;

        TextView text = new TextView(this);

        text.setTextSize(100);
        text.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        // text.setText(message);
        text.setText(counter);

        setContentView(text);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the right way to do it.

```
text.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
```

Comment: +1 This, or `String.valueOf`, is the best answer. Using `+` implicitly creates a `StringBuffer` object to concatenate with `""`.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
text.setText(""+counter);
```

instead of

```
text.setText(counter);
```

to display integer value in TextView becuase [TextView.setText(CharSequence text)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) only accept Strings to display not any other datatype

Comment: Thanks.  :)  Answers my question.  On a side note...is there an alternative way to do this?

Comment: yes we have all ways by which we can convert an integer to string

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In the end both of these worked fine.

```
text.setText("Remaining Attempts: " + String.valueOf(counter));
text.setText("Remaining Attempts: " + counter);
```

My issue was the text box wasn't long enough and the counter fell on the second line that was hidden.

Sharing just in case someone else makes the same mistake I did.